# How to to get links report with Google Search Console API?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client, google-search-console

I am currently trying to develop a tool to use Google Search Console API in order to get some data from my website.
My main goal is to get the 'Links Report' such as Top linking domains & Top linked pages in an automated way.

I don't know if this is available via Google API. I have found nothing till now.

Is this even possible to get such list via the Google Search Console API?

Comment: After multiple searches, I think the simple answer is, I can't do that through the API. 
There is currently no endpoint supporting gathering backlinks from Google Search Console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing, hoping someone will answer that question